# eclipse scout image change

Tags: image, eclipse-scout

I am trying to change image inside Image view.

I know that `getTestImageField().setImageId(Icons.Logo);` would not work, because it would not refresh renderer.

Because I need to use `setImage()`, I need a way to get Image from `Icons` class.

As Patrick suggested I try

```
final IconProviderService provider = SERVICES.getService(IconProviderService.class);
final IconSpec ic = provider.getIconSpec(AbstractIcons.StatusError);
final byte[] content = ic.getContent();
```

but my problem is that `ic` is always `null`.

While I debug this I notice that inside `IconProviderService.class` in line 57 :

```
@Override
protected URL findResource(String fullPath) {
  URL[] entries = FileLocator.findEntries(m_hostBundle, new Path(fullPath));
  if (entries != null && entries.length > 0) {
    URL url = entries[entries.length - 1];
    if (LOG.isDebugEnabled()) {
      LOG.debug("find image " + fullPath + " in bundle " + m_hostBundle.getSymbolicName() + "->" + url);
    }
    return url;
  }
  return null;
}
```

`URL[]` entries is always empty no matter witch icon I try to present.

After further debugging I found out that `FileLocator` tries to find fragments from bundle, and then look for the path inside this fragments. (`line 242`)

```
Bundle[] fragments = activator.getFragments(b);
```

but `Bundle[] fragments` is always null.

Normally my bundle `b` is `(Bundle) EquinoxBundle : org.eclipse.scout.rt.ui.rap.mobile_4.0.100.20140829-1424`.

I want to try with different bundle so I do  :

```
final BundleContext context = Activator.getDefault().getBundle().getBundleContext();

for (final Bundle b : context.getBundles()) {

    final IconProviderService provider = SERVICES.getService(IconProviderService.class);
    provider.setHostBundle(b);
    final IconSpec ic = provider.getIconSpec(AbstractIcons.StatusError);
    if (ic != null) {
        final byte[] content = ic.getContent();
        imageField().setImage(content);
    }
}
```

but `fragments` (from above code) is always null.

Comment: That sounds like a hard nut to crack. Could you please add the following info:
Do icons work for you at all? (getConfiguredIconId on a table column for example)
Where is the icon file (the png) located that you want to show?
Where is the corresponding Icons class located (the java file)?
In which bundle do you retrieve the icon?
What is the value m_hostBundle in AbstractIconProviderService during the call to retrieve the IconSpec?

Comment: Yes setting icons is working. If I set getConfiguredIconId it works and if in code set setIconId and update page it works either. Icons are default icons that comes inside Scout, or Icons that I add (client/resources/icons/...). Icons.class is in Shared folder (root). The bundle as I posted is : org.eclipse.scout.rt.ui.rap.mobile.

Comment: I try to set different bundle provider.setHostBundle(Activator.getDefault().getBundle()); but it did't work either.

Comment: I forget, I try to set icon inside form and inside client bundle (different class)

Comment: I add edit question (Edit 3)

Comment: This question is impossible to follow... So many EDITs...

Comment: Would you like to change my question ?

Comment: I edit question so it is more readable

Answer (score 1):

You can obtain the image content (`byte[]`) that you can set on the image field as follows:

```
IconProviderService provider = SERVICES.getService(IconProviderService.class);
byte[] content = provider.getIconSpec(Icons.YourIconName).getContent();
getImageField().setImage(content);
```

I quickly checked it and it works for me.
Please ensure that the icon is available and you set up the icon provider service as explained in this [Wiki Article](https://wiki.eclipse.org/Scout/HowTo/5.0/Add_an_icon)

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but when I try this I get provider.getIconSpec(Icons.YourIconName) = null; code final IconProviderService provider = SERVICES.getService(IconProviderService.class);
      final byte[] content = provider.getIconSpec(AbstractIcons.StatusError).getContent(); gave me a nullPointer exception